# AppFabric .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard, appfabric

Is there any library used to interact with AppFabric compliant with .NET Standard o .NET Core?
All the library I could find on nuget are related to ServerAppFabric.Client which seems be compiled only for .Net Framework 4.X
I know Microsoft already ended AppFabric support but for the moment changing the caching mechanism in the entire architecture would be the last option.

Comment: Although appfabric is not metioned directly i could look like using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer could be the solution reading this article :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1